# Why would correlation for daily data be higher than weekly data?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, seasonality

I'm running a multiple linear regression on 2 years of daily sales data. When running against the daily data, I get a correlation of 84%, but when summarized to weekly totals, the correlation over the same period drops to 68% with the same underlying inputs/output. How/why would this be?

Further, hold-out testing shows this daily regression to be more predictive *at the weekly level* than the weekly data regression. How could this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen all the time in financial time series. I would invert the question: why do you think the series must be correlated to the same degree at different sampling frequencies?

Say you have two stationary time series, maybe autocorrelated. In the long run they must not be correlated much. They're stationary after all, right? However, in a short run they might moving  together.

To make it even more obvious. Imagine two perfect sine waves with period one week. If you sample them or average at weekly frequency they'll look like a constant line. You measure correlation, and it will be zero. However if you sample at any higher frequency then you'll see the sine wave, and the correlation will be 1.

Here's a numerical example. Note, that the correlation doesn't go to zero because of the rounding errors, but it changes significantly when I change the sampling frequency:
[image]

What this demonstrates is a stylized version of a scenario where daily traffic (blue dashes) leads the daily sales (red). The correlation is a perfect 1. So you have a lot of traffic then in a 3.5 days the sales spike. That's the top plot.

Now, you decide to sample at weekly frequency, and maybe sum up all traffic during the week, and get the bottom plot. Since the sales and traffic were stale, you don't really see the changes weekly. All the dynamics is in daily. Not surprisingly, here your correlation drops to 0. As I wrote due to rounding errors, it's not really 0 but still much smaller than perfect.

The MATLAB code:

```
n = 101;
x = (1:n)';
y = sin(2*pi/10*x);
y2 = sin(2*pi/10*x+pi);
figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot([y y2],'-.')
title(sprintf('\\rho = %f',corr(y,y2)))

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(1:10:n,[y(1:10:n) y2(1:10:n)],'+')
title(sprintf('\\rho = %f',corr(y(1:10:n), y2(1:10:n))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm operating from a set of assumptions about my data set here... For context, my X inputs are sales activities and I'm attempting to predict customer traffic as the Y. There is definitely intraweek seasonality, but I would have expected any relationship between sales and the traffic driving those sales to hold between daily and weekly samples.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to say. There's no statistical or mathematical reason for correlations to hold when sampling frequency changes. It may or may not. More often not.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking for is the practical rationale for why daily swings in an *result* of traffic (e.g. a sale) would be predictive, but weekly swings in the same outcome wouldn't be.

In other words, if 10 sales implied 100 customers (10% purchase) in a day, then why wouldn't 70 sales imply 700 customers (again, 10% purchase) in a week? I realize this isn't a statistical point-of-view for looking at this, but since it is ultimately the question I am trying to answer I'm hoping to understand where the relationship breaks down.

Comment: It's a great question, but it's not statistical at this point. It's more of a domain knowledge. I don't deal with sales forecasting in retail, so I'll give you a scenario that applies to my domain. For instance, as I wrote earlier if your sales are stale, i.e. not really growing in past few months, and traffic is also stale, not growing, BUT they both vary weekly. The retail sales as well as internet traffic MUST be weekly cyclical. In this scenario it's easy to see how at daily frequency you detect a stronger relationship than at weekly. That's what my silly example is demo'ing

Comment: This drove it home - of course weekly sales are cyclical! :) You lose the relationship between sales and traffic when they both average out week-over-week. There's less variability for the model to capture, so it's harder to fit the line. Thanks!